# How can I add distortion to a voronoi texture?

Tags: texturing, procedural, shader-nodes

By running a Voronoi texture through a map range node to invert it (for some reason I don't understand this works better than an invert node) and a color ramp node, I get the following result

[image: voronoi texture]

Now I would like to add some randomness to the edges of the cells, so that they become squiggly instead of being straight lines. After some experimenting with noise textures I got the following result

[image: added noise texture]

this adds some random thickness to the cell edges, but they are still straight, so it is not quite what I was looking for.

How can I make the edges of the cells in a Voronoi textures more squiggly?

Comment: Quick answer: mix a _Noise_ texture into the _Vector_ input... for a long answer I haven't got time at the moment, but I'm sure someone will prepare one.

Comment: ...by the way, the first _Map Range_ node is absolutely unnecessary since you can simply switch black and white on the _Color Ramp_.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann I realized that I can also substitute both the colorramp and map range with a simple math node set to "less than" and a low enough threshold to obtain the same result. I've been trying to introduce some noise in the vector input of the Voronoi texture, but I keep getting some cool [modern art](https://i.imgur.com/loG09vO.png) instead of anything close to having a recognizable cell structure!

Comment: Yes, a _Math_ node could be used as well, I didn't suggest that since you have left the _Color Ramp_ interpolation at _Linear_, whereas the _Less Than_ corresponds to the _Constant_ interpolation. Didn't know if this was intentional. Oh, and what the moderators like to say: please don't rely on external links for resources like screenshots. You can put the full resolution images in your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To randomize the edges of the cells, you can take a *Noise Texture* node and use it to distort the original texture coordinates.

Since the *Voronoi Texture* (and others) use *Generated* texture coordinates by default, they work without the need to plug something into the *Vector* input. However, to mix in the noise you need to get the *Texture Coordinate* node as input.

There you can either use the *Generated* or the *Object* output (the difference is not too relevant for this question) and mix it with the noise *Color* output in a *Mix RGB* node (set to *Linear Light* for example) which you then plug in the voronoi's *Vector* socket.

Now you can tweak and experiment with the settings to get a result you like. *Scale*, *Detail*, *Roughness* and *Distortion* of the noise all have an influence on the outcome and especially the factor in the *Mix RGB* node, I would suggest you start with a very low value.

Note: Here I used the *Object* output, if you do this it presumably means you have to change the *Scale* in the *Voronoi Texture* to get a similar result as with *Generated* or none. I also plugged the coordinates into the *Noise Texture* which is not mandatory. Without, the *Noise Texture* uses *Generated* coordinates, it only helps for consistency if both textures use the same coordinate system.

[image: voronoi crackle]

Comment: I cannot upvote your answer because I don't have enough reputation, but it worked perfectly. Mixing the object's coordinate with the noise is the part I was missing, I was trying to plug the noise directly into the Voronoi's vector, which in hindsight makes no sense!

Comment: @CasualBlenderer Accepting the answer is absolutely sufficient, it signalizes others who stumble across this question that a working solution was found (so it's in a way even better than just upvoting it). Well, to manipulate the Voronoi's vector like in your case it's not suitable to plug the noise in directly, since it completely replaces the original vector. But it all depends on what you want to achieve, for other effects this might be exactly what you want ;)